# "consise" SQL table scripting via Powershell SQLServer module

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting

When I script a database using Visual Studio, I get a more "consise" script like the one below, where constraints are included in the create table statement. I'm wondering if there is an option to script this same way using the Powershell SQLServer module. All the options I have tried to this point script the constraints after the create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE [Adv].[ReportMaster] (
    [ReportID]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportMaster_ReportID] DEFAULT (newid()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [GroupID]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ReportTypeID]   INT              CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportMaster_ReportTypeID] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]      BIT              CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportMaster_IsActive] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CustType]       VARCHAR (8)      NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn]      DATETIME         CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportMaster_CreatedOn] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedOn] DATETIME         CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportMaster_LastModifiedOn] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]     VARCHAR (32)     NULL,
    [LastCalc]       SMALLDATETIME    NULL,
    [IsArchived]     TINYINT          DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ReportMaster_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReportID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Adv_ReportMaster_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [Ply].[Customer] ([CustomerID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportMaster_ReportGroup] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupID]) REFERENCES [Adv].[ReportGroup] ([GroupID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [IX_ReportMaster1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([GroupID] ASC, [CustomerID] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
);
```